# Why the bit operation i & (-i) equals to rightmost bit?

Tags: math, bit-manipulation

I learned Fenwick Tree algorithm and there was written "i & (-i) equals to rightmost bit". 
For example, `3 & (-3) = 1, 48 & (-48) = 16.`. 

I tested the result for `i <= 64`, and all values satisfied the condition. 
But I don't know why the condition satisfies (proof) for all positive integer i. 

Please tell me how to prove.

EDIT: You can assume that i is 32-bit integer (But 16-bit is ok). If so, the range of value i is `1 <= i <= 2^31-1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you've got a two's complement binary number `i`:

```
0b1101001010000000
```

and you want to find `-i`. Well, `-i` is the number such that `i + (-i) == 0`. So what number has that property? Well, if you construct another number:

```
 i: 0b1101001010000000
-i: 0b0010110110000000
```

such that the rightmost set bit is the same as in `i`, all bits after that are `0`, and all bits before that are the inverse of those in `i`:

```
 i: 0b11010010 1 0000000
-i: 0b00101101 1 0000000
```

then when you add these numbers together, the carries propagate off the left side of the number and just leave all 0 bits, so this is `-i`.

Now, what do we get if we `&` these numbers? Well, the trailing zeros `&` together to produce zeros. The bits on the left are opposites in `i` and `-i`, so they `&` together to produce zeros. But the rightmost set bit is `1` in both `i` and `-i`, so that's the only set bit in `i & -i`.

```
     i: 0b11010010 1 0000000
    -i: 0b00101101 1 0000000
i & -i: 0b00000000 1 0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

It even works for negative integers, it doesn't really matter, we can prove it for bitstrings in general.

First the `i != 0` case:

Using string notation,

-(a10<sup>k</sup>) = (~a)10<sup>k</sup> (either by definition, or by working out `-x = ~x + 1`)

Note that a number that isn't 0 is always in the form a10<sup>k</sup>, that is, it start with "anything", then has a rightmost 1 followed by any number of zeroes (maybe zero zeroes).

Then,

a10<sup>k</sup> & (~a)10<sup>k</sup> = 10<sup>k</sup> ('a' cancels with its inverse)

For the 0 case, well, there is no rightmost 1 so it isn't in the result either.

Comment: What is 10^k used? I am asking about a question for binary numbers.

Comment: @square1001 it's string notation, so a 1 followed by k 0's

Answer (score 1):

When you decrement a two's complement integer, you:

1. Find the right-most 1 bit and set it to 0; and
2. Set all the lower-order bits to 1

`i-1`, therefore, has all the 1 bits that `i` has, except the right-most one.

The complement, `~(i-1)`, therefore shares *no* 1 bits with `i`, except he rightmost one,  so `i & ~(i-1)` contains only the right-most 1 bit in `i`.

This can be simplified a bit if we note that `~x = -x-1`, so `~(i-1) = -(i-1)-1 = -i`.  So the right-most 1 bit in `i` is just `i&-i`