# what is the meaning of k-=(k & (-k)) in c?

Tags: c, loops

A function to calculate sum where I encountered with this statement ..plz help

```
 int get_sum(int x) {
     int p = 0, k;
     for (k = x; k > 0; k -= k & -k)
         p += bit[k];
     return p;
 }
```

Comment: Where and how is `bit[]` declared - defined?

Comment: Where is `k` defined, and what type of `k` is?

Comment: sorry the more correct dupes are [meaning of (number) & (-number)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12818978/995714), [how to understand `i & -i` in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42192185/995714), [Why the bit operation i & (-i) equals to rightmost bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41969429/995714), [Why is “i & (i ^ (i - 1))” equivalent to “i & (-i)”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24772669/995714). Those can easily be found if you've googled for `"i & (-i)" site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 4):

This expression:

```
k -= (k & (-k))
```

Is a tricky way of taking the least significant bit that is set in a positive number and clearing that bit.  It is dependent on two's compliment representation of negative numbers.

The first part, `k & (-k)` isolates the least significant bit that is set.  For example:

`1 & -1`:

```
   00000001
 & 11111111
   --------
   00000001
```

`2 & -2`:

```
   00000010
 & 11111110
   --------
   00000010
```

`24 & -24`:

```
   00011000
 & 11101000
   --------
   00001000
```

When this value is subtracted from the orignal `k`, it clears that bit as a result.

So as the loop progresses, the value of `k` is reduced 1 bit at a time, starting with the lowest.  So if for example `x` was 52, `k` would be 52, then 48 (52 - 4), then 32 (48 - 16), and would exit at 0 (32 - 32).

As to why the program is doing this, that depends entirely on the definition of `bit` and what it stores.