# Сalculate the weight of each byte of number x

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, byte, hammingweight

While learning C++, i decided to get some knowledge of assembly. So i have to count weight of each byte of some number.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int x=0;
    int count = 0;
    cout << "Enter number\n";
    cin >> x;
    int z = 8;
    _asm
    {
        mov ebx, z;
        mov eax, x;
        xor ecx, ecx;
    l:
        cmp ebx, 0;
        jne k;
        jmp m;
    k:
        test eax, 11111111;
        shr eax, 1;
        adc ecx, 0;
        dec ebx;
        jmp l;
    m:
        mov count, ecx;
    }
    
    cout << "Counted " << count << " bits";
    return 0;

}
```

Now it works corret only for 1 byte numbers, how to empower this program for 2 bytes and more?

.......................................

Comment: what is the "weight of a byte" ?

Comment: `test eax, 11111111` followed by `shr eax, 1` makes the test instruction a no-op. Even if not, the immediate number seems very odd. Did you intend it as a hexadecimal number?

Comment: `test eax, 11111111` is useless. Obviously `z` is the number of bits, if you have written this code you should know that. So change that as needed.

Comment: @ecm I assume that was meant to be binary to test the least significant byte.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Maybe it's [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58995487/10871073)?

Comment: Note that C++ already has the tools for this in the [<bit>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit) header. We don't write much assembly nowadays.

Comment: Note that `11111111` is a decimal constant, `0xa98ac7`.  Did you maybe mean `0xff`?  Or `test al,al`?  Of course there's no reason to do a `test` here; the `adc` is using the bit shifted out (into CF) by `shr`

Comment: Are you looking for separate counts for each byte?  Like positional popcount with 8-bit bins?  With AVX-512 BITALG, you'd want `vpopcntb` for that.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpopcnt .  Otherwise do the usual SWAR bithack but stop at 8-bit bins.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "Weight" is just another term for "population count"