# BLSI instruction - Isolate lowest set bit

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, instruction-set, bmi

Bit Manipulation Set contains [BLSI](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi#:%7E:text=BLSI%20%E2%80%94%20Extract%20Lowest%20Set%20Isolated%20Bit%20,set%20bit%20from%20r%2Fm64%2C%20and%20s%20...%20) - this instruction `Extracts the lowest set bit from the source operand and set the corresponding bit in the destination register`

Could you show an example illustrating what is referred to by `the lowest set bit` (last bit in binary representation of an operand ?), what is the performed operation, and in which context or for which kind of applications this operation is used ?

Comment: Did you try evaluating `(-x) & x` for some `x` values to see what happened?  https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks explains how / why this and other bithacks work. (e.g. carry propagation through zeros vs. ones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest set bit is the *least significant 1 bit*. For example in 1010110101**1**0000 then the first 1 bit on the right beside `0000` is the lowest set bit, and `_blsi_u32(0b101011010110000)` returns `0b10000`

The operation has also been described in the link above:

```
temp ← (-SRC) bitwiseAND (SRC);
SF ← temp[OperandSize -1];
ZF ← (temp = 0);
IF SRC = 0
    CF ← 0;
ELSE
    CF ← 1;
FI
DEST ← temp;
```

`(-SRC) bitwiseAND (SRC)` clears all but the least significant 1 bit. For more information about how that works read

- [Why is "i & (i ^ (i - 1))" equivalent to "i & (-i)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24772669/995714)
- [how to understand i & -i in python? bit manipulation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42192185/995714)
- [Why the bit operation i & (-i) equals to rightmost bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41969429/995714)
- [meaning of (number) & (-number)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12818978/995714)

It's commonly used to iterate through the set bits, for example to [count the number of set bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/995714) (not the most efficient method though), or to pack/deposit bits:

- [Portable efficient alternative to PDEP without using BMI2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38938911/995714)
- [Standard C++11 code equivalent to the PEXT Haswell instruction (and likely to be optimized by compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144237/995714)

It's also used in the [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree). See [sample C++ implementation](https://algorithmist.com/wiki/Fenwick_tree)

Comment: Unfortunately, my *GenuineIntel G3220* doesn't support BMI so I have to stay with good old instruction `BSF`, `BSR`.

Comment: @vitsoft: If you want to isolate the LSB without BMI instructions, you'd actually use `xor eax,eax` / `sub eax, edi` / `and eax, edi` to implement `(-x) & x`.  Using `bsf` / `bts` (into an xor-zeroed reg) would be less efficient, especially if you care about portable performance on AMD CPUs.

Comment: https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks has nice explanations of *why/how* many of these lowest-set-bit bithack formulas work, with carry/borrow propagation through zeros vs ones.